# Can a string be inserted at a specific line in a file from the CLI?

Tags: linux, echo

The file has the content:

```
[Greet]

Hello
Hi
Hola
```

I want to add a string called `Hey` so that its position is after `Hello`:

```
[Greet]

Hello
Hey
Hi
Hola
```

Is there a way to do the above by using `echo` or other native linux tools from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed`.

Since the `sed` command to insert or append lines requires a line break it is easiest to place the `sed` command in a file and tell `sed` to execute that file.

Example: to insert `Hey` after (every) `Hello`, create the following file:

```
/Hello/a\
Hey
```

Then invoke `sed`:

```
sed -f appendheyafterhello.sed < sourcefile > resultfile
```

[Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-append-insert-replace-and-count-file-lines/) are more `sed` commands including how to insert a line *before* a pattern or at a specific line number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some perl solutions:

```
perl -p -i -e 'print "Hey\n" if /Hi/'  filename
```

or

```
perl -p -i -e 'print "Hey\n" if $. == 4'  filename
```

or

```
perl -n -i -e 'print; print "Hey\n" if /Hello/' filename
```